# How to convert a mov to a gif without loosing quality

Tags: macos, mac, ffmpeg, homebrew

I am trying to convert a mov I have created by recording my screen with Quicktime (I am running Mac OS El Capitan) but the result is far from perfect.
I am using ffmpeg (installed using homebrew) but the end result is disappointing.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: That’s impossible because the GIF format is limited to a 256-color palette.

Answer (score 1):

I use the app GIF Brewery. It can create a nice looking GIF of movies and screencasts.

First, you'll want to crop the recording to just what you need to reduce the file size. Click the **Crop** button. Use the handles to isolate only the part you care about. Then press **Return** on your keyboard:

[image: screenshot of cropping the video]

Next you'll want to fiddle with the export settings to ensure good quality with a low file size. Click on the **GIF Properties** button. Use the following settings:

- Frame count: 24
- Frame delay: 100 ms
- Reduce the number of colors in GIF: [On], Adaptive Palette, 192 Colors
- Improve GIF quality with dithering: [On], Sierra Lite

[image: screenshot of GIF properties]

Finally, click the **Create GIF** button and select a location to save the file. You'll have a GIF that looks almost as good as an MP4.